# How to set Debian/GNOME to normally end transmission when shutting down?

Tags: debian, gnome, shutdown, transmission

I'm using transmission and if i forget quit it before i shutdown computer it checks torrents at start-up like when i kill it.

I don't know where is problem in Debian, GNOME or Transmission configuration. I use transmission as user, not via daemon.

Comment: transmission-gtk or the daemon?

Comment: transmission-gtk. It's written in question ;)